# Spring KafkaEmbedded Testing listener is not consuming message

Tags: spring-test, spring-kafka

i like to unit test some spring kafka listeners. This works fine in production, but i have some problems with the unit tests. I defined the configuration complettly with spring configuration beans but the listener is never called. Did i miss something?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {KafkaSpringBootTest.class})
@Configuration
@DirtiesContext
public class KafkaSpringBootTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes", embeddedKafka.getZookeeperConnectionString());
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset", "earliest");
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransferListener kafkaTransferListener() {
        return new KafkaTransferListener();
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testSendMessage() throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("now sending");
        kafkaTemplate.send("test", "hello");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}

class KafkaTransferListener {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "test")
    public void listen(String test) {
        System.out.println("received message via kafka: " + test);
    }
}
```

Versions:

- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.0.0.RELEASE
- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.11.0.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest`? If not, you are probably sending the messages before the has started. DEBUG logging should help track down the problem.

Comment: Hi Gary, i uploded the log-file https://gist.github.com/itstata/86c025379ae5e4356f919bc3ab4f740d#file-2017-10-19_spring_kafka_log and updated the code. For me it looks like the listeners are initialized before the message is produced.

Comment: There is nothing about `Consumer` in your logs. See my answer for possible reason. You just don't have anything about `ListenerContainer`! You definitely need `@SpringBootApplication` or do all the `@EnableKafka` "magic" manually

Comment: Thank you gary - it's now working fine. The final reason was my bad spring configuration. I removed nearly everything from the testclass.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see `@SpringBootApplication` configuration to be sure that Spring Kafka is auto-configured.
2. You use `KafkaEmbedded` and its properties to configure `ProducerConfig`, but at the same time I don't see how you configure `ConsumerConfig`. Essentially you should use the same properties from  the `EmbeddedKafka`.
3. With the Boot auto-configuration you really don't need all that kung-fu. There is a simplest way to configure everything against `EmbeddedKafka`:

   ```
   @BeforeClass
   public static void setup() {
       System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
       System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes", embeddedKafka.getZookeeperConnectionString());
   ```

   }

And you definitely must have `@SpringBootApplication` class in the same package as this test. Everything rest will be done by Boot.

See [this sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/test-embedded-kafka) on the matter.

Comment: Hi and thank you: 1.@SpringBootTest ist doing the job instead of @SpringBootApplication. I want to manually configure all beans; 2. I added the consumer, but it's still not working; 3. I want to mock some beans in future (without profiles), that's the reason for the manual configuration beans code

Comment: I'm not sure in your claim about `@SpringBootTest`, but let it be: I'm here not convince you in some religion. If you are going to use everything manually, you should consider to add `@EnamleKafka` to let the Framework to scan `@KafkaListener`s: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-listener-annotation

Comment: You still can mock beans auto-configured by Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: wow - very cool. Tank you - i will test this out. It look's much better.